# I was trying to create a Shutdown on my laptop with Voice through python. but I had a bug that I couldn't handle

Tags: python

The truth is that I have been looking on the internet and nobody seems to have a problem similar to the one I have and I am getting a little crazy. I have seen if it can be a problem that the module is not installed properly or something but it seems that everything is in order. I'm using Python 3.9 version, Pycharm IDE, Pyttsx3 last version, and Windows10.**strong text**
I have been trying for hours. But I couldn't handle it. I'd appreciate it if you helped. here is my problem

```
C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe "E:/Python project/project 5.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pyttsx3\__init__.py", line 20, in init
    eng = _activeEngines[driverName]
  File "C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\weakref.py", line 134, in __getitem__
    o = self.data[key]()
KeyError: None

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Python project\project 5.py", line 48, in <module>
    Speak("Do you want to shutdown your computer sir?")
  File "E:\Python project\project 5.py", line 42, in Speak
    engine = pyttsx3.init()
  File "C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pyttsx3\__init__.py", line 22, in init
    eng = Engine(driverName, debug)
  File "C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pyttsx3\engine.py", line 30, in __init__
    self.proxy = driver.DriverProxy(weakref.proxy(self), driverName, debug)
  File "C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pyttsx3\driver.py", line 50, in __init__
    self._module = importlib.import_module(name)
  File "C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 790, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pyttsx3\drivers\sapi5.py", line 10, in <module>
    import pythoncom
  File "C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pythoncom.py", line 2, in <module>
    import pywintypes
  File "C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\win32\lib\pywintypes.py", line 105, in <module>
    __import_pywin32_system_module__("pywintypes", globals())
  File "C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\win32\lib\pywintypes.py", line 87, in __import_pywin32_system_module__
    raise ImportError("No system module '%s' (%s)" % (modname, filename))
ImportError: No system module 'pywintypes' (pywintypes39.dll)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

my code

```
import pyaudio
import pyttsx3
import speech_recognition as sr
import os
def take_commands():
    #initializing speech_recognition
    r=sr.Recognizer()
    #opening physical microphone of computer
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        print('Listening')
        r.pause_threshold=0.7
        audio=r.listen(source)
        try:
            print('Recognizing')
            #Recognizing audio using google api
            Query=r.recognize_google(audio)
            print("The query is printed='",Query,",")
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            print('Say that again sir')
            return 'None'
        import time
        time .sleep(2)
        return Query
#crating speak() function to giving speaking power
def speak(audio):
    # initializing pyttsx3 module
    engine=pyttsx3.init()
    #anything  we pass inside engine.say()
    #will be spoken by our voice assistant
    engine.say(audio)
    engine.runAndWait()
speak("Do you want to shutdown your computer?")
while True:
    command=take_commands()
    if 'no' in command:
        speak('Thank you sir I will not shut down the computer')
    if 'yes' in command:
        command.speak('Shutting the computer')
        os.system('shutdown /s /t 30')
        break
    speak('say that again sir')
```

Comment: I assume you've tried installing `pywintypes`?

Comment: You're not using Python 3.8.  You're using Python 3.9.  If you're surprised by that, then you may have installed some packages where you didn't expect to.

Comment: Since this is an error that has other questions about it on this site, along with several possible solutions, please show us what solutions you've tried already, so that we don't waste time by suggesting things you've already done. If you haven't yet searched for a solution, then you should do that before posting here.

Comment: Captin Trojan  no man

Comment: Try creating a virtual environment and use that to install the required libraries again.
Your error message is an import error, by using a virtual environment, you make sure that you use the correct python version and libraries for it. PyCharm supports this approach.